# See exception events on the google analytics platform

Tags: google-analytics

Google analytics advertise a way to track exceptions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/exceptions

I send those exception events to google analytics (I see the http calls being sent to google analytic), but there is no way to see those exceptions in the google analytic dashboard. How do you see those exceptions in the google analytic dashboard?